# Do Rpi3 UART devices inherit their device ID from the on-board UART0 controller (GPIO pins 8 & 10)?

Tags: serial, windows-iot, uart, input-device

I am working on a device prototype which reads load cell data to an Arduino which sends the load cell data via (hardware, not USB) Serial to the Rpi3 running Win10 IoT.

The communication link between the devices works using the Serial test app by Microsoft found at: https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/SerialUART/CS

What I am trying to figure out is: in the device list of the Serial app, a device is *always* listed as **BCM2836#0** followed by what looks like a vendor/hardware ID string. I realize this is the name of the onboard UART controller by which I access the data at the serial port.

However, for the app I am developing I need to automatically connect to the serial port on pins #8 and #10 without having the user select the device. There will only be one serial device in the entire system. Can I then simply open the com port at this address--(in other words, assume the Arduino inherits the identifier from the Pi's UART controller?)

Reference: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking.  I believe you plan to use Windows IoT on the Pi.  The name you use for the UART will be that exposed by Windows IoT.

Comment: You've not mentioned which model of Pi you're using and I've not used *Windows IoT* but I'd guess that "BCM2386#0" might be joined by "BCM2386#1" if you were to disable the Bluetooth module (thus releasing the associated PL011 serial port) and might be swapped over if you were to swap *PL011* and *mini UART* in the device tree. Are you asking if there's a way to make sure you're connecting to the UART attached to the GPIO pins each time regardless of changes made to the device tree (i.e. `pi3-disable-bt` and `pi3-miniuart-bt`)?

Comment: Excellent insight despite my lack of important information. I am using a Raspberry Pi 3B, with Windows IoT 10.017763.107. You are 100% correct: I am asking how to connect to, and be sure I am connected to the UART attached to the GPIO pins #8 & #10 (Tx, Rx, respectively). How would I address the UART at these pins?

Comment: Virtually all the information in the link to the Foundation site is Linux specific.

Comment: I assume its the C# UWP app you are talking about. Search the internet for finding COM ports using C# - There is a weird way to enumerate them, then basically using the result you select if progromatically and connect to it. Good luck